Animals On Parade - German Musical Cartoon
I took an Intro German course in 1976 and the instructor showed us a fantastic musical cartoon show with a theme something like "Animals On Parade". Can anyone guess what this might have been and where I might find it? It was tremendously involved and lasted at least 20 or 30 minutes....animation set to music, sung in German.

Could it have been an excerpt from Die Konferenz der Tiere?

That HAS to be it...and yet I remember it differently??? I found excerpts on YouTube but none of them quite matched my distant memory. Yes, it wasn't a parade, it was a conference that they were going to....but there was singing in German about all the different animals as they marched through the forest. I even remember that it was a kind of triplet rhythm..."the AN-i-mals On -....-pa RADE... (not those words of course). Maybe I'm imagining all this but none of the excerpts on YouTube quite matched up.
